# swashbuckle/swagger ui not validating guid format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

If I have parameter of guid in my webapi action, the swagger UI will validate the format and not let me enter something that doesn't match the guid format.

This is my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GuidTestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GuidTestController> _logger;

    public GuidTestController(ILogger<GuidTestController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost("GuidTest")]
    public string GuidTest(Guid id)
    {
        return $"{Request.ContentType}: {Request.ContentLength}";
    }
}
```

This is the generated swagger json:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "WebAPI.Test",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {

   "/GuidTest/GuidTest": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "GuidTest"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "uuid"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": { }
}
```

This all works.  if, in the swagger ui I enter a malformed guid, the textbox shakes and makes me correct the value.

I'm trying to create an operation filter that lets me create a multipart request.  As a test, one part will be a guid and one part will be binary

It looks like this:

```
public class MultipartOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply the filter to the operation only if it is decorated with the attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody() { Required = false };

        operation.RequestBody.Content.Add("multipart/form-data", new OpenApiMediaType()
        {
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Type = "object",
                Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>()
                {
                    {"a_guid",new OpenApiSchema()
                        {
                            Type="string",
                            Format = "uuid",
                            Title = "This is a guid"
                        }
                    },
                    {"a_file",new OpenApiSchema()
                        {
                            Type="string",
                            Format = "binary",
                            Title = "file upload"
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

And my controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("MultiPartFormData")]
public string MultiPartFormData(Guid id)
{
    return $"{Request.ContentType}: {Request.ContentLength}";
}
```

the resulting swagger.json looks like this:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "WebAPI.Test",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/MultipartFilterTest/MultiPartFormData": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "MultipartFilterTest"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "uuid"
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "a_guid": {
                    "title": "This is a guid",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "uuid"
                  },
                  "a_file": {
                    "title": "file upload",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   
  },
  "components": { }
}
```

The swagger ui will create well formed multipart request, but it doesn't validate that the guid value in the first part is formatted correctly, although it does validate that the guid parameter is the correct format.  Is this just a shortcoming of either swagger or possible swashbuckle?

[image]

Comment: `The swagger ui will create well formed multipart request, but it doesn't validate that the guid value in the first part is formatted correctly, although it does validate that the guid parameter is the correct format. ` Your word is a bit contradictory. In your picture,the first part is not formatted correctly and it validates failed.It seems no error.

Comment: @Rena - The first 'part' (named "id") is from the query parameter, not from one of the sections in the multi-part body.  That one validates,  the one that is the first part of the body (named "a_guid" does not)